How to Evaluate this Sum
I am trying to evaluate this summation
$$
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{k} \gamma^\ell \binom{2k + m}{\ell}
$$
where $k$ and $m$ are non-negative integers and $\gamma$ is a real number. I tried using Mathematica but did not get any answer. Is there any way to express this sum in terms of a special function for a arbitrary $m$? or any other technique? Only for $m$ equals 0 I can express the sum in terms of a hypergeometric function.

My guess is, you won't find a closed formula for anything but $m=0,$ and even then not sure. This is because there isn't a close form when $\lambda=1.$

Maple says
$$
\sum _{L=0}^{k}{x}^{L}{2\,k+m\choose L}= \left( 1+x \right) ^{2\,k+m}-
{x}^{k+1}{2\,k+m\choose k+1}{\;\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,-k+1-m;\,k+2;\,-x)}
$$
but that is little more than the definition of the hypergeometric function.

Thanks...that's good enough for me!

There is also a form with the incomplete beta function
